# Open source certificate authority software

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I am looking for a open source implementations of certificate authority software, where I want to generate Root CA certificate and install it on my client machines, and generate SSL certificates for my local websites and install it on the webservers.

I believe, if I install root CA certificate on my client machines, the browsers wouldn't be showing me the certificate errors ... is that right ??

I found this wiki node http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority  and they have a list of open source softwares:  EJBCA, OpenCA, OpenSSL, gnoMint, DogTag, XCA, r509.

I am not sure which one will a be good choice for me, if anyone has any experience with it please share with us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right regarding browser complaining about certificate. If you install Root CA certificate into your trusted certificate store and server certificates will be signed by this Root CA, you won't see error messages any more.

I think for your purposes OpenSSL is what you need. You should be able to create all necessary certificates in just several commands.